# School network, nexus 6p keeps trying

Tags: wi-fi, wpa2, nexus-6p

My new Nexus 6p won't connect to the WiFi network at school, a WPA2 PSK network(802.1x EAP). It only says "Trying to connect..."("Verbinding maken" in Dutch). I think this will be a common problem, so that's why I am asking it here.

Groetjes,

Arend-Jan
PS: Yes I have got the right ID and password.

Comment: Try static IP like 192.168.1.9. It happens when dhcp/router lacks to provide an IP to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ask to your school Network manager , if they are using **Mac Address Filter** , because if they are using the Mac Address Filter , you wont be able to connect to Wi-Fi even with right ID and Password...

If they are using Mac Address filter in their router , Make sure to give them your device Mac address so you can connect to the Wi-Fi

Comment: I did some research on other websites and contacted the Google help desk, and it seems that our radius server(to check if the credentials are ok) has a wrong tls1.2 implementation, it tries to use it, but it sends wrong codes back, so the phone can't connect to it. I went to it guys, but the only response for updating the servers was: "won't happen". I think they have to because windows 10, IOS 9.1 and android 6.0 use the tls1.2 version, but when?